# Using LFO to Control Amplitude

Tags: reaktor, lfo

I want to be able to route an oscillator through an LFO that controls the amplitude.

This is what I have tried:

[image: Simle Amplitude LFO]

It *sort of* works, however, the amplitude control on the LFO functions as On/Off.

In the noise module I'm working on, the same (?) configuration isn't having any effect:

[image: Noise module]

How is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I'm starting to realize that digging into the Factory Ensembles (and blocks) is probably the best way to figure out how Reaktor works.

I opened up Carbon, Kaleidon and Nanowave and it was pretty overwhelming. However Nanowave has a pretty simple implementation of an LFO in it's `waves` module:

[image: Nanowave waves module]

Through which I saw that it's (more complex) LFO receives the `gate` input, and is *previous* to the oscillator, with output feeding into the Linear Amplitude input on the oscillator.

I briefly experimented with pasting that module itself into my project, but for now am just using the basic approach, here in the MVP:

[image: basic analog LFO implementation]

And here in the little noise module:

[image: little noise LFO implementation]