# Adjusting Reaktor Module Level (-60 - 0) with LFO Output

Tags: reaktor, lfo

I've asked [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/100275/using-lfo-to-control-amplitude) about LFO's before and am still making sense of how to use Oscillator outputs. In this [blog article](https://morgansynthesis.wordpress.com/control-signals-part-i-lfos-and-envelope-generators) the writer discusses the conversion of output values from an LFO, but I still can't seem to get it.

The below macro receives the "Level" from the sound generator (a resonant noise generator), which goes between `-60` and `0`:

[image: Macro]

The "Level" numeric output from the LFO, though intermittent, seems to confirm it outputs numbers between `-1` and `1`. I don't really understand how that relates to the "sub-audio rate, typically between  0 Hz to around 24 Hz" that I believe it oscillates at.

I have attempted multiplying it by various values, then subtracting that from the Main "Level"s number which comes into the Macro.

The outer macro looks like this:

[image: Outer Macro]